# How to crop a background image when using sprite

Tags: css, image, background

here is the file  : http://studioteknik.ca/stackoverflow_question/test1.html i need to see only one background image at the time, let's say the second. It's 400 pixel from the top, but i need it image to be crop top 400 height. HOW TO DO THAT ?

Comment: i would suggest you split these images into seperate files and display as neccessary

Comment: Sprite is a lot faster to display many image without loading it. And if it's really a background images ? can i just clip/crop it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general **content** images should not be backgrounds or sprites, they should be inline images using the `IMG` tag. Sprites are usually reserved for UI elements such as icons and menu elements.

```
<div class="sprite1"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.sprite1 { 
        height:400px;
        width:400px;
        background-image:url(http://www.studioteknik.ca/stada/wp-content/themes/stada-theme/images/banner_sprite.jpg);
        background-position:0 -400px; 
    }
```

Comment: What about if the the background image is 800px but the container div is only 400px ? How to resize ?

Answer (score 1):

I use a pseudo element (before/after) to generate the box size I want for the sprite and add the background-image to that.

That way you can set the 'normal' element to `position: relative` and the `:after` to `position: absolute;`.

Then position the `after` as you want it in relation to the main container and the size of the after element prevents any more of the image sprite 'bleeding out'.

I documented that technique more fully here: http://benfrain.com/image-sprites-data-uris-icon-fonts-v-svgs/

Answer (score 0):

Yes - that's a good answer. Generally, you position a sprite exactly the way you would position a normal image, but set the height and width so that they only cover one portion of it. The background position is the only thing that changes. If I had a 40 pixel high sprite and wanted to display it has 2 20px high images, the code would be this:

```
  .sprite1{ height:20px;
 width:20px;
 background-image:url("myimage.jpg");
  background-position: 0 0;
 }

.sprite2{
height:20px;
width:20px;
background-image:url("myimage.jpg");
background-position:0 -20;
}
```